# matlab function parser on gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I need to do a parser on my gui in matlab in which you can type your own function formula that will be used for computations. I came up with to make function that gets function from edit box as a string and saves it to m-file as a function. But any further calling changed file do not bring expected results if the first form of function were stored in memory. Do you have any other ideas to solve it?

Comment: Code to help us help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the code to an m-file, take a look at the [`eval` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html).

Comment: You can additionally use evalc, feval or other "evaluation" functions that may fit more to your case @Mateusz